# Unable to Use Look Behind Pattern (?<=pattern) In REGEXP_SUBSTR In Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Hi I have following Query Text
"DROP TABLE "DB"."SCHEMA"."TABLE_A"  and I would like to extract Table Object from this Query text as  "DB"."SCHEMA"."TABLE_A" ; i am using following Reg. exp pattern
(?<=DROP\s+[TABLE]+\s+).[A-Za-z0-9"_.]+ ; this expression is perfectly working fine in JavaScript based Procedure in Snowflake , I am able to get the expected extract, but when i used this in following Snowflake SQL REGEX_SUBSTR function i am getting error as "no argument for repetition operator: ?"

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(QUERY_TEXT,'(?<=DROP\s+[TABLE|VIEW|PROCEDURE]+\s+).[A-Za-z0-9"_.]+',1,1,'im')
```

Any idea what is the issue with this pattern in expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use the following expression?

```
select REGEXP_SUBSTR(QUERY_TEXT,'.*DROP\\s+[TABLE|VIEW|PROCEDURE]+\\s+([A-Za-z0-9"_.]+)',1,1,'ime') as object_name
from values ('DROP TABLE "DB"."SCHEMA"."TABLE_A"'),
('DROP view "DB"."SCHEMA".view_b'),
('DROP procedure "DB"."SCHEMA"."proc( varchar varchar)"')
tmp (QUERY_TEXT);

+-------------------------+
|       OBJECT_NAME       |
+-------------------------+
| "DB"."SCHEMA"."TABLE_A" |
| "DB"."SCHEMA".view_b    |
| "DB"."SCHEMA"."proc     |
+-------------------------+
```

Comment: thanks sir @ Gokan Atil for your quick response , where can i find regex specific documentation for Snowflake

Comment: You are welcome. Simeon also provided the URL: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake explicitly does not support [back references](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-regexp.html#backreferences) in the SQL regular expressions

The work around is to use a JavaScript function, which you have already found, this is not an issue, because given "all rows loaded in a partition are processed" you can just do a subquery to exclude the rows you want, if you are doing a large join.